# Compare two array key values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have below code,
**$tables** contains all tables available in the system and **$order_info** contains all current orders, that contains table_id as well,

Now I want to show only those tables which table_id is not in **$order_info** array.

```
@foreach($tables as $t)
@foreach($order_info as $o)
    @if($o['table_id'] != $t->table_id)
        <option value="{{$t->table_id}}">{{$t->table_number}}</option>
    @endif
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

obviously above code is showing me duplicate table numbers because I am looping it for two arrays,
How can I show only those tables which are not in **$order_info**

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You have to write your code like this -

```
@foreach($tables as $item)   
    @if(! in_array($item->table_id,array_column($order_info,'table_id')))
       <option value="{{$item->table_id}}">{{$item->table_number}}</option>
    @endif   
@endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach($tables as $item)   
    @if(array_search($item->table_id, array_column($order_info,'table_id')) == false)
       <option value="{{$item->table_id}}">{{$item->table_number}}</option>
    @endif   
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks friends for help,
Found some easy way in Laravel,

```
@foreach($tables as $t)
    @if (! $order_info->contains('table_id', $t->table_id))
        <option value="{{$t->table_id}}">{{$t->table_number}}</option>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be easier to perform that in the `Controller` directly

I supposed you have Two Models `Order` and `Table` and you have define relation between those two models like this

```
class Table extends Model {
    public function oders(){
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
    }
}

class Order extends Model {
    public function table(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Table');
    }
}
```

So in the controlle which render the `view` in which you perform the loop you can render order like this

```
public function ...() {

    $order_info = Order::where('...', '')->get();
   
    $tables = Table::whereDoesntHave('order', function($query){
        $query->whereNotIn('id', $order_info->pluck('id'));
    });
    
    return view('...', compact('tables', 'order_info'); 
}
```

Here as you have already list of `order_info` you can return only table which order with a given `id` doesn't exist like this

```
$tables = Table::whereDoesntHave('order', function($query){
    $query->whereIn('id', $order_info->pluck('id'));
});
```

Here I use `pluck` to return an array of `id` of `orders` in the `order_info` table.

Answer (score 0):

actually it will not return duplicate.
first loop

```
@foreach($tables as $t)

@endforeach
```

it will return a value
then second loop will start
it will compare the previous single value with all the values from order_info.
.
again first loop will return a value. then 2nd loop will iterate for each individual  value returned by the first loop .